# How can i append a dynamic angular parameter to an url?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, href, querystringparameter

I am working on a project that uses typescript and angularjs. I have to insert the reference to a dynamic link as in the example:

```
http://..../Detail.aspx?code={{MyCode}}
```

where myCode is a dynamic parameter to insert at the end of the URL.
How do you advise me to take action? could the use of the ng-href directive help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="http://..../Detail.aspx?code={{MyCode}}"> Mylink </a>
```

will work normally provided `MyCode`  contains value and is within the scope.

Answer (score 0):

In your $routeProvider configuration set reloadOnSearch to false:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/items', {
controller: 'ItemsCtrl',
templateUrl: '/templates/items',
reloadOnSearch: false
},
...
);
```

and in your controller use $location.search() to set the id param:

```
$location.search('id', 123);
```